# How to add Value to the existing Property in Artifactory by REST

Tags: artifactory

If Artifacory property already exists the value I am trying to set (PUT) overrides the existing value of that property.

Is there a way to avoid making GET Property combine them and PUT

Looking for a simple flag or trick

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory has recently introduced a PATCH method for properties. From the WIKI:

> Update Item Properties Description: Attach and modify properties to an
>   item (file or folder). When a folder is used property attachment is
>   recursive by default.Notes: Requires Artifactory Pro.
>
> Since: 6.1.0 Security: Requires a privileged user (Annotate
>   authorisation required) Usage: PATCH
>   /api/metadata/{repoKey}/{itemPath}?[&recursive=1] Produces:
>   application/json

Sample Usage:

```
PATCH /api/metadata/libs-release-local/org/acme?[recursive=1]
{
    "props":{
        "newKey": "newValue",
        "existingKey": "modifiedValue",
        "toBeRemovedKey": null
    }
}
```

Props that will not be mentioned will not be changed.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ItemProperties

Comment: The Patch is useful for these who wants to update the Key. In my case I update the value. And there might be more then one Value for one Key.